# Selecionar texto automaticamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou tentando criar uma função que percorra um texto qualquer selecionando letra por letra como o efeito de você passar o mouse selecionando um texto devagar.

Usei o `select()` mas ele seleciona todo o texto.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function SelectText(element) {
  var doc = document;
  var text = doc.getElementById(element);
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = doc.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(text);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = doc.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(text);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);

  }
}
$('p').click(function() {
  SelectText("selectme");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="selectme">Silvio Santos Ipsum É fácil ou não éam? Mah é a porta da esperançaam. Ma vai pra lá. É por sua conta e riscoamm? Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm. O arriscam tuduam, valendo um milhão de reaisuam. Ma! Ao adquirir o carnê do Baú, você estará concorrendo
  a um prêmio de cem mil reaisam. Eu não queria perguntar isso publicamente, ma vou perguntar. Carla, você tem o ensino fundamentauam? Ma quem quer dinheiroam? Estamos em ritmo de festamm. Eu só acreditoammmm.... Vendoammmm. Ma vejam só, vejam só. É com
  você Lombardiam.</p>
```

Acredito que o efeito de selecionar o texto não pode ser disparado automaticamente ( apenas chamando uma função sem acionar um evento). precisei de um evento click para que ele fosse acionado.

Como posso fazer este efeito?

Comment: Você quer selecionar somente a letra que o mouse estiver, ou  o texto todo?

Comment: Coloca cada palavra dentro de uma tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para essa resposta vou considerar apenas os navegadores que seguem o padrão, dessa forma não vai funcionar no IE (talvez adaptando o método usado no primeiro `if` do código na pergunta).

Para que você possa selecionar uma parte do texto é necessário atribuir a seleção no elemento [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Text) ao invés do HTMLElement, utilizando [`Range.setEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setEnd), que recebe uma posição como parâmetro.

Para fazer a animação utilizei [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

```js
var selecionar = document.body.children[0];
var textNode = selecionar.childNodes[0]; // elemento Text
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(textNode, 0); // define início da seleção
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  range.setEnd(textNode, range.endOffset + 1); // expande seleção
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  if (textNode.length === range.endOffset) {
    // terminou animação, termine a execução
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 50);
```

```html
<p>Cursus curae odio vestibulum nec ullamcorper in at quisque ac etiam vestibulum scelerisque euismod quis vitae a a nibh curae. A consectetur aliquet cras ac scelerisque tristique scelerisque.</p>
```

Nota: a seleção aparece com fundo cinza devido ao `<iframe>` do site não estar com foco ativo, mas executar esse código em uma página funciona como esperado.

Answer (score 1):

A solução do Sanção sem duvidas parece melhor, mas como eu ja estava fazendo uma também, segue abaixo o código, nesse é possivel pegar qualquer `<p>` da pagina por exemplo, mas tem umas desvantagens como o uso da função sleep, que mostra um alert toda hora, só marcar a checkbox para não exibir mais que funciona (execute em uma pagina web fora daqui pois o alert não é executado no stackoverflow)

```
<p id="selectme">Silvio Santos Ipsum É fácil ou não éam? Mah é a porta da esperançaam. Ma vai pra lá. É por sua conta e riscoamm? Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm. O arriscam tuduam, valendo um milhão de reaisuam. Ma! Ao adquirir o carnê do Baú, você estará concorrendo
  a um prêmio de cem mil reaisam. Eu não queria perguntar isso publicamente, ma vou perguntar. Carla, você tem o ensino fundamentauam? Ma quem quer dinheiroam? Estamos em ritmo de festamm. Eu só acreditoammmm.... Vendoammmm. Ma vejam só, vejam só. É com
  você Lombardiam.</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>

<script>
var text = $('#selectme').text();
var array = [];
for(var i in text) { array.push(text.charAt(i)) }
$('#selectme').html('')
;

for (var i in array) { $('#selectme').append("<span>"+array[i]+"</span>") }

function SelectText(element) {
  var p = $('#selectme');
  p.children().each(function(index, child) {
       var selection = window.getSelection();
       var range = document.createRange();
       range.setEnd(child, range.endOffset + 1); // expande seleção
       selection.removeAllRanges();
       selection.addRange(range);
       sleep(50);
  });
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
    alert("");
}

$('p').click(function() {
  SelectText("selectme");
});
</script>
```

o ideal seria mesclar as duas para obter uma solução mais completa para o problema